# How extend onRenderAdminForm function for plugin validly?

Tags: joomla2.5

I am creating new plugin for Joomla 2.5 for my own purposes. And the question is in the title. I am trying to do following in my class:

```
function onRenderAdminForm(&$item, $type, $tab = '') {
    parent::onRenderAdminForm($item, $type, $tab);
}
```

But this doesn't make any sence. It doesn't work. Excluding this code from my class makes my plugin work properly.

Any help or links would be helpful.

Comment: `return parent::onRenderAdminForm($item, $type, $tab);` ? If the parent returns something...

Comment: Thanks! How blind I were!